# Intermittent connection to to Oracle DB using an Oracle Java Stored Procedure

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, java-stored-procedures

We are wanting to connect to an Oracle DB from our Oracle DB.  We were not able to create a DB Link, so we are using a Java Stored Procedure loaded into our DB and connecting using the loaded JDBC.  The weird thing is, I'm able to connect and retrieve information about half the time.  The other half, it times out and I get the following stacktrace:

[image]

Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: please avoid pictures of text and instead just paste the text (formatted preferably)

Comment: It would be good to see some of the code where you're establishing the connection (or whichever lines the error is occurring)